# Is it possible to use "Achieve" in negative sentences

Tags: word-choice, verbs, ielts

I've noticed in IELTS reading that there was a sentence as below:

> disappointing results were *achieved* by the Australian Academy.

I looked this verb up in Longman dictionary, It's been said that:

> To get a good result or succeed in doing something.

It has positive meaning. How we could use "***achieve***" with the above sentence? Is it correct? Is this a good use of the verb?

Comment: The sentence _The administration has achieved precisely nothing_ is perfectly grammatical. And, once again, dictionaries do not prescribe uses or meanings. _Achieve_ certainly **can** have that meaning in some cases. Equally certainly, it **doesn't** have that meaning in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case it actually is being used in the sense you describe - even though the results were disappointing, they did **achieve results**, which is a typical positive use of achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think using it in that way is perfectly fine. Some quick Googling revealed the following phrases:

> They *achieve* a very negative result, one which I have to think, is not what they really want.
>
> The development sector is *achieving* failure
>
> Astros *achieve* loss #105 by getting shut out by the Cardinals

Although in each of these cases, it seems to be used somewhat ironically.

Comment: +1: yes there can definitely be an ironic implication in that context.

Answer (score 0):

You can say you have achived nothing from going to school, which is a typical negative use of the subject word.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can use it negatively but may require some form of positive element to the clause.

> John just about managed to achieve a passing grade.